# i can not add informations to my table at mysql. i use javascript to show an information message and it doesnot do anything then

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

this is my php code to add to my database. dbConfic.php is my connection to database. I have tried it for the others page i made and it works fine.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['Send'])) {
        include('dbConfig.php');
        $date=$_POST['lname'];
        $comm=$_POST['fname'];  
        $username1=$_POST['address'];
        $id1=$_POST['costname'];

        $sql="INSERT INTO damage (damageid, damagetype, description,damagedate,damagecost)
        VALUES (NULL,'$date', '$comm', '$username1','$id1')";
        if ($sql){          
            echo "Insert successful";
        } else {
            echo "Insert failed.";
        }
    }
```

my form is in the same page: and have 4 text fields and 2 buttons. For the button send i use javascript at the seperate js document. My js works fine and shows the message i want but the information dont add to database.

```
    <p>type of damage:<input type="text" name="lname" size="60">
    <br>
    description:<input type="text" name="fname" size="60">
    <br>
    Date of record damage:<input type="text" name="address" size="60">
    <br>
    Estimated cost<input type="text" name="costname" size="60">
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="Send" value="send" onclick="respond();">
    <input type="reset" value="reset">
    </p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `IF` statement will always result in `true`

```
$sql="INSERT INTO damage (damageid, damagetype, description,damagedate,damagecost)
VALUES (NULL,'$date', '$comm', '$username1','$id1')";
if ($sql){          
    echo "Insert successful";
} else {
    echo "Insert failed.";
}
```

I think what you're trying to do is

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", $user, $pass);
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute();

if ($result) {
  // success
}
else {
  // fail
}
```

You want to test the result of running your query, not testing the `$sql` string itself.

Comment: Since he didn't post any of his mysql query code, how do you know he's using the deprecated interface? Why do you use the wrong interface in your answer instead of posting the PDO version?

Comment: @Barmar, sorry about that.

Comment: variable $db what it is?? i have my db connection code to seperate php script(dbCongic.php)

Comment: @user3808157, I've added a line to show you how to create `$db`. I suggest you read more about [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: i tried everything but it did not work. And then i change my button type to submit and it works!! whats the difference between button and submit?

Comment: Well a button can do whatever you'd like. A submit button triggers the `submit` event on the form.